# .test() method is not working in react jsx code

Tags: validation, reactjs, jsx

I'm using .test() method to check the input value from the text box is matching with regex in my react app, below is my code

```
if(!((data.regex_tx).test(value))){
        message = <p style={{color:'red',marginTop:-15}}>{data.vld_msg}</p>
  }
```

where data.regex = regex from json, value = input value from textbox and data.vld_msg=validation message from json to be displayed. Getting console error  " Uncaught TypeError: data.regex_tx.test is not a function(…)". Anything wrong in the syntax. Kindly help

Comment: What is `data`? What is `value`? What does it mean "not working"?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: data.regex and data.vld_msg are values which Im getting from json object and while running the above code I'm getting below error. " Uncaught TypeError: data.regex_tx.test is not a function(…)"

Comment: How do you pass regexp via json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `data.regex_tx` is just a `string` as it is fron JSON. You have to convert the `string` to `RegExp` and then call the `test` function. Do something like below

```
var expr = new RegExp(data.regex_tx);
if(expr.test(value)) {
 // other code
}
```